# Issue with @markpieszak/ng-application-insights after Angular 6 Update

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights, angular6

i'm having an issue with a insight service after updating to angular 6.

after the complete update i try to run ng serve and i get this message even though it compiles.

ERROR:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(InsightsModule)[AppInsightsService -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppInsightsService -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9217)
    at _createClass (core.js:9264)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:9234)
```

Answer (score 0):

Giovanni i don't know if eventually you fixed the problem, but routing module was updated from angular 6, so you need to ensure that after the update, you have the required libs installed (specially the @angular/router) and you have the proper configuration on the app-routing.module file.